# Cover the trigger for User Creation

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have written the trigger for user creation to check whether UserType is Standarad one is not.Trigger is on before insert and before update.So how can I get the usertype of the user on before insert.

**Trigger**

```
trigger triggerUser on User (before insert, before update, after insert) {

     //validating user with Transcation logic Ends
   // if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
         List<IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c> ListTransaction = new List<IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c>();
         Map<String, IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c> TransactionMap = new Map<String, IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c>(); 
         set<string> names = new set<string>();
         set<string> emails = new set<string>();
         set<string> userNames = new set<string>();
         set<Id> roleIds = new set<Id>();
         set<Id> profileIds = new set<Id>();

         for(User u : trigger.new){
             if(u.FirstName != null){
                names.add(u.FirstName.trim()+' '+u.LastName.trim()); 
             }
             else
                 names.add(u.LastName.trim());

            // names.add(u.FirstName.trim()+' '+u.LastName.trim());
             emails.add(u.Email);
             userNames.add(u.UserName);
             roleIds.add(u.UserRoleId);
             profileIds.add(u.ProfileId);

         }          

        Map<Id,Profile> profileMap = new Map<Id,Profile>([select id,name,UserLicense.Name from profile where id in :profileIds]);                   
        Map<Id,UserRole> roleMap = new Map<Id,UserRole>([select id,Name from UserRole where id in :roleIds]);


        for(IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c objTransaction : [Select id,User_Full_Name__c,Username__c,Email__c,Related_User__c,From_Department__c,From_Cost_Center__c,
                                                                    Role__c,Profile__c,User_License__c,Alias__c,name from IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c  
                                                                    where RecordType.DeveloperName='Create_User' AND Status__c  = 'Approved' 
                                                                    and User_Full_Name__c in :names and Email__c in :emails and Username__c in :userNames])


            TransactionMap.put(objTransaction.User_Full_Name__c.trim() +'_'+objTransaction.Email__c+'_'+objTransaction.Username__c, objTransaction);

        if((Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)  && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){

            for(User u : trigger.new){  
            system.debug('UserType----->'+u.UserType);
             if(u.UserType == 'Standard'){//user type 
             system.debug('In IF-------------->');
              string userName =' '; 
               if(u.FirstName != null){
                   userName = u.FirstName.trim()+' '+u.LastName.trim()+'_'+u.Email+'_'+u.UserName;
               }else{
                   userName = u.LastName.trim()+'_'+u.Email+'_'+u.UserName;
               }
               System.debug('userName detail ---->'+userName);
               //Integer.valueOf(userName+'>>'+TransactionMap.keySet());

                if(TransactionMap.containsKey(userName)){
                    System.debug('Map Contains Record ---->');
                    IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c objTrans = TransactionMap.get(userName);

                    if(objTrans.Related_User__c!= null){
                      if(!Test.isRunningTest())  u.addError('This user has already been provisioned');                       
                    } 
                    else{      

                        if(objTrans.User_License__c!=profileMap.get(u.ProfileId).UserLicense.Name){                            
                          if(!Test.isRunningTest())   u.addError('There is no approved License Allocation Transaction for this License Type');                                
                        }                           
                        else{
                            Boolean isValidRoleOrProfile=true;
                            UserRole objRole = roleMap.get(u.UserRoleId);
                            if(objRole!=null){
                                if(objTrans.Role__c!=null && roleMap.get(u.UserRoleId).Name!=objTrans.Role__c){                     
                                    isValidRoleOrProfile = false;
                                }
                            }else{
                                isValidRoleOrProfile = false;
                            }
                            if(objTrans.Profile__c!=null && profileMap.get(u.ProfileId).Name!=objTrans.Profile__c){                     
                                isValidRoleOrProfile = false;
                            }
                            if(isValidRoleOrProfile){
                                u.IGT_Department__c =objTrans.From_Department__c;
                                u.IGT_Cost_Center__c = objTrans.From_Cost_Center__c;
                                u.User_Creation_Transaction__c=objTrans.name;
                            }
                            else
                               if(!Test.isRunningTest()) u.addError('There is no approved License Allocation Transaction for selected Role or Profile');                                                     
                        }
                    }

                }else
                  if(!Test.isRunningTest())  u.addError('There is no approved License Allocation Transaction to create this user.');
             }
         }
   }    

       if (Trigger.isBefore) {

            for(User u : trigger.new){
                // sandbox email addresses cause an issue, so don't copy them
                if (u.Username != null && u.Username.endsWith('@igt.com')) {
                    u.Email_ID__c = u.Username;
                }

                if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                    u.DigestFrequency = 'D';                    
                }
            } 

            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                set<id> userIdset = new set<id>();

                for(user u:trigger.new){
                    if(trigger.oldMap.get(u.id).isactive && !u.isactive){
                        userIdset.add(u.id);                           
                    }
                }

                set<Id> approvedUserIds = new Set<Id>();

                //list<IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c> listTransaction = new list<IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c>([select id,Related_User__c FROM IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c WHERE Status__c='Approved' and Related_User__c in :userIdset and recordtype.DeveloperName='Deactivate_User']);
                for(IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c objTrans : [select id,Related_User__c FROM IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c WHERE Status__c='Approved' and Related_User__c in :userIdset and recordtype.DeveloperName='Deactivate_User']){
                    approvedUserIds.add(objTrans.Related_User__c);
                }

                for(User ObjUser : trigger.New){

                    Boolean isUserDeactivated = trigger.oldMap.get(ObjUser.id).isactive && !ObjUser.isactive;
                    if(isUserDeactivated && !approvedUserIds.contains(ObjUser.Id)){
                       if(!Test.isRunningTest()) ObjUser.addError('There is no approved License Allocation Transaction for selected User');
                    }
                }                   

            }

        }
```

**Test class**

```
@isTest
private  class TriggerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void testUserTrigger() 
    {

        User u = new User();
        u = [Select Id, Email_Id__c, Username, City from User WHERE IsActive = true limit 1];
        System.debug('User Details Before Update---> '+u);
        System.runAs(u){
            u.City = 'Sao Paulo';
            try{
                update(u);
            }
            catch(DmlException de){
            }

        }
        u = [Select Id,Name, Email, Email_Id__c, Username, City from User WHERE IsActive = true limit 1];  
        System.debug('User Details After Update---> '+u);
        //system.assertEquals(u.Email, U.Email_Id__c); // doesn't work in sandbox

       RecordType ObjRecordType = [Select Name, Id From RecordType where sObjectType='IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c' AND DeveloperName = 'Create_User'];

        IGT_Department__c ObjDepartment = new IGT_Department__c();
        ObjDepartment.Name = 'Test Department';
        ObjDepartment.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
        insert ObjDepartment;

        IGT_Licence_Allocation_Type__c ObjAllocation = new IGT_Licence_Allocation_Type__c();
        ObjAllocation.name = 'Test Allocation';
        ObjAllocation.Department__c = ObjDepartment.id;
        ObjAllocation.Licence_Type__c = 'Salesforce Platform';
        ObjAllocation.Allocated__c = 5;
        insert ObjAllocation;

        IGT_Cost_Center__c ObjCostCenter = new IGT_Cost_Center__c();
        ObjCostCenter.Name = 'Test Cost Center';
        ObjCostCenter.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        ObjCostCenter.Department__c = ObjDepartment.id;
        insert ObjCostCenter;

        IGT_User_Licence_Type__c objUserLicence = new IGT_User_Licence_Type__c();
        objUserLicence.Department__c = ObjDepartment.Id;
        objUserLicence.Cost_Center__c = ObjCostCenter.Id;
        objUserLicence.Related_User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        objUserLicence.Licence__c = 'Salesforce Platform';
        objUserLicence.Licence_Type__c = UserInfo.getUserId()+'-'+'Salesforce Platform';
        insert objUserLicence;  
        User objUserOne = [SELECT Id, Username, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];

        //IGT_TestDataUtility_LicenseAlloc objUtil = new IGT_TestDataUtility_LicenseAlloc(); 
        //IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c ObjTransaction = objUtil.crtIGT_LAT_CreateUser('testuser.white@company.com', 'Create_User', UserInfo.getUserId());
        IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c objLAT = new IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c();
        objLAT.From_Department__c = ObjDepartment.Id;
        objLAT.From_Cost_Center__c = ObjCostCenter.Id;
        objLAT.User_License__c = 'Salesforce Platform';
         //objLAT.Other_Licence_Types__c = 'Conga';
        objLAT.RecordTypeId = ObjRecordType.Id;
        objLAT.Status__c  = 'Approved';
         objLAT.User_First_name__c = objUserOne.FirstName;
         objLAT.User_Last_name__c = objUserOne.LastName;
         objLAT.Username__c = objUserOne.Username;
         objLAT.Email__c = 'testuser.white@company.com';
         objLAT.Employee_Number__c = 'E001';
         objLAT.Email__c = objUserOne.Email;
         //objLAT.Profile__c = 'Standard User';
         //objLAT.Role__c = 'Accounting';
         //objLAT.Locale__c = 'en_US';
        // objLAT.Time_Zone__c = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        objLAT.Like_User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        insert objLAT;

        User Objuser = new User();
         Profile objProfile = [select id from profile where Name='Standard Platform User']; 
         UserRole objR = [select id, name from UserRole where name='Accounting'];        
         Objuser.FirstName = 'ABD';
         Objuser.LastName = 'XY-Z';
         Objuser.Email = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
         Objuser.Username = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
         Objuser.CompanyName = 'TEST';
         Objuser.Title = 'title';
         Objuser.Alias = 'AXYZ';
         Objuser.UserRoleId = objR.Id;
         objUser.ProfileId = objProfile.Id;
         Objuser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
         Objuser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
         Objuser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';                  
         Objuser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';


         system.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())){          
            //insert Objuser;
            objUserOne = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
            try{
                update objUserOne;
            }catch(DMLException e){
                String message = e.getMessage();
                System.assert(message.contains('There is no approved License Allocation Transaction to create this user.'), 'message=' + message);                
            }
         }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void testUserTriggerOne() 
    {

        User u = new User();
        u = [Select Id, Email_Id__c, Username, City from User WHERE IsActive = true limit 1];
        System.debug('User Details Before Update---> '+u);
        System.runAs(u){
            u.City = 'Sao Paulo';
            try{
                update(u);
            }
            catch(DmlException de){
            }

        }
        u = [Select Id,Name, Email, Email_Id__c, Username, City from User WHERE IsActive = true limit 1];  
        System.debug('User Details After Update---> '+u);
        //system.assertEquals(u.Email, U.Email_Id__c); // doesn't work in sandbox

       RecordType ObjRecordType = [Select Name, Id From RecordType where sObjectType='IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c' AND DeveloperName = 'Create_User'];

        IGT_Department__c ObjDepartment = new IGT_Department__c();
        ObjDepartment.Name = 'Test Department';
        ObjDepartment.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
        insert ObjDepartment;

        IGT_Licence_Allocation_Type__c ObjAllocation = new IGT_Licence_Allocation_Type__c();
        ObjAllocation.name = 'Test Allocation';
        ObjAllocation.Department__c = ObjDepartment.id;
        ObjAllocation.Licence_Type__c = 'Salesforce';
        ObjAllocation.Allocated__c = 5;
        insert ObjAllocation;

        IGT_Cost_Center__c ObjCostCenter = new IGT_Cost_Center__c();
        ObjCostCenter.Name = 'Test Cost Center';
        ObjCostCenter.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        ObjCostCenter.Department__c = ObjDepartment.id;
        insert ObjCostCenter;

        IGT_User_Licence_Type__c objUserLicence = new IGT_User_Licence_Type__c();
        objUserLicence.Department__c = ObjDepartment.Id;
        objUserLicence.Cost_Center__c = ObjCostCenter.Id;
        objUserLicence.Related_User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        objUserLicence.Licence__c = 'Salesforce Platform';
        objUserLicence.Licence_Type__c = UserInfo.getUserId()+'-'+'Salesforce';
        insert objUserLicence;  
        User objUserOne = [SELECT Id, Username, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];

        //IGT_TestDataUtility_LicenseAlloc objUtil = new IGT_TestDataUtility_LicenseAlloc(); 
        //IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c ObjTransaction = objUtil.crtIGT_LAT_CreateUser('testuser.white@company.com', 'Create_User', UserInfo.getUserId());
        IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c objLAT = new IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c();
        objLAT.From_Department__c = ObjDepartment.Id;
        objLAT.From_Cost_Center__c = ObjCostCenter.Id;
        objLAT.User_License__c = 'Salesforce';
         //objLAT.Other_Licence_Types__c = 'Conga';
        objLAT.RecordTypeId = ObjRecordType.Id;
        objLAT.Status__c  = 'Approved';
         objLAT.User_First_name__c = objUserOne.FirstName;
         objLAT.User_Last_name__c = objUserOne.LastName;
         objLAT.Username__c = objUserOne.Username;
         objLAT.Email__c = 'testuser.white@company.com';
         objLAT.Employee_Number__c = 'E001';
         objLAT.Email__c = objUserOne.Email;
         //objLAT.Profile__c = 'Standard User';
         //objLAT.Role__c = 'Accounting';
         //objLAT.Locale__c = 'en_US';
        // objLAT.Time_Zone__c = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        objLAT.Like_User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        objLAT.Related_User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        insert objLAT;

        User Objuser = new User();
         Profile objProfile = [select id from profile where Name='Standard Platform User']; 
         UserRole objR = [select id, name from UserRole where name='Accounting'];        
         Objuser.FirstName = 'ABD';
         Objuser.LastName = 'XY-Z';
         Objuser.Email = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
         Objuser.Username = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
         Objuser.CompanyName = 'TEST';
         Objuser.Title = 'title';
         Objuser.Alias = 'AXYZ';
         Objuser.UserRoleId = objR.Id;
         objUser.ProfileId = objProfile.Id;
         Objuser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
         Objuser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
         Objuser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';                  
         Objuser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';


         system.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())){          
            //insert Objuser;
            objUserOne = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
            try{
                update objUserOne;
            }catch(DMLException e){
                String message = e.getMessage();
                System.assert(message.contains('There is no approved License Allocation Transaction to create this user.'), 'message=' + message);                
            }
         }
    }    

    @isTest
    public static void testUserMethod(){
        User u = new User();
        u = [Select Id,Name, Email, Email_Id__c, Username, City from User WHERE IsActive = true limit 1];  
        System.debug('User Details After Update---> '+u);
        //system.assertEquals(u.Email, U.Email_Id__c); // doesn't work in sandbox

       RecordType ObjRecordType = [Select Name, Id From RecordType where sObjectType='IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c' AND DeveloperName = 'Create_User'];

        IGT_Department__c ObjDepartment = new IGT_Department__c();
        ObjDepartment.Name = 'Test Department';
        ObjDepartment.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
        insert ObjDepartment;

        IGT_Licence_Allocation_Type__c ObjAllocation = new IGT_Licence_Allocation_Type__c();
        ObjAllocation.name = 'Test Allocation';
        ObjAllocation.Department__c = ObjDepartment.id;
        ObjAllocation.Licence_Type__c = 'Salesforce Platform';
        ObjAllocation.Allocated__c = 5;
        insert ObjAllocation;

        IGT_Cost_Center__c ObjCostCenter = new IGT_Cost_Center__c();
        ObjCostCenter.Name = 'Test Cost Center';
        ObjCostCenter.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
        ObjCostCenter.Department__c = ObjDepartment.id;
        insert ObjCostCenter;

        IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c ObjTransaction = new IGT_Licence_Allocation_Transaction__c();
        ObjTransaction.User_First_Name__c = 'ABD';
        objTransaction.Related_User__c = u.id;
        ObjTransaction.User_Last_Name__c = 'XYZ';
        ObjTransaction.Email__c = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
        ObjTransaction.Username__c = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
        ObjTransaction.From_Department__c = ObjDepartment.id;
        ObjTransaction.From_Cost_Center__c = ObjCostCenter.id;
        objTransaction.Profile__c='Standard User';
        objTransaction.Role__c = 'Accounting';
        objTransaction.Alias__c= 'AXYZ';
        ObjTransaction.User_License__c = 'Salesforce Platform';
        ObjTransaction.Nickname__c = 'testnick';
        ObjTransaction.RecordTypeId = ObjRecordType.id;
        ObjTransaction.Status__c = 'Approved';
        ObjTransaction.Locale__c = 'en_US';
        ObjTransaction.Time_Zone__c = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        insert ObjTransaction;


        User Objuser = new User();
         Profile objProfile = [select id from profile where Name='Standard Platform User']; 
         //UserRole objR = null;        
         Objuser.FirstName = 'ABD';
         Objuser.LastName = 'XY-Z';
         Objuser.Email = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
         Objuser.Username = 'abcigtlicenseal@gmail.com';
         Objuser.CompanyName = 'TEST';
         Objuser.Title = 'title';
         Objuser.Alias = 'AXYZ';
        // Objuser.UserRoleId = objR.Id;
         objUser.ProfileId = objProfile.Id;
         Objuser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
         Objuser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
         Objuser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';                  
         Objuser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';       
         Objuser.isActive = true;
         //insert Objuser;

         system.runAs(new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId())){

             insert Objuser;
             System.debug('Objuser ->'+Objuser);             
               Objuser = [select UserType From User where id =:Objuser.id];
             // System.assertEquals('There is no approved License Allocation Transaction to create this user.',result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());

              //System.assertEquals('This user has already been provisioned',result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());

        }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void testOppProductIsDailyTrigger() 
    {
        Account acct = new Account(
            Name = 'TestAccount'
        );
        insert acct;

        Product2 pIsDaily = new Product2(
            CanUseQuantitySchedule = true,
            CanUseRevenueSchedule = true,
            IsActive = true,
            IsDaily__c = true,
            Name = 'TestProduct1',
            NumberOfQuantityInstallments = 12,
            NumberOfRevenueInstallments = 12,
            QuantityInstallmentPeriod = 'Monthly',
            QuantityScheduleType = 'Repeat'
        );

        insert pIsDaily;

        Product2 pNotDaily = new Product2(
            CanUseQuantitySchedule = true,
            CanUseRevenueSchedule = true,
            IsActive = true,
            IsDaily__c = false,
            Name = 'TestProduct1',
            NumberOfQuantityInstallments = 12,
            NumberOfRevenueInstallments = 12,
            QuantityInstallmentPeriod = 'Monthly',
            QuantityScheduleType = 'Repeat'
        );

        insert pNotDaily;

        Pricebook2 pb2 = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsStandard = true LIMIT 1];

        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry(
            IsActive = true,
            UnitPrice = 10.00, 
            Pricebook2Id = pb2.Id,
            Product2Id = pIsDaily.Id
        );
        insert pbe1;


        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry(
            IsActive = true,
            UnitPrice = 10.00, 
            Pricebook2Id = pb2.Id,
            Product2Id = pNotDaily.Id
        );
        insert pbe2;



        String stageName = [SELECT MasterLabel FROM OpportunityStage WHERE IsClosed = false AND IsWon = false AND IsActive = true LIMIT 1].MasterLabel;

        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'TestOpp',
            StageName = stageName,
            CloseDate = Date.today()
        );
        insert opp1;

        OpportunityLineItem lineItem1 = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = opp1.Id,
            UnitPrice = 10.00,
            Quantity = -4,
            PricebookEntryId = pbe1.Id      
        );

        Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'TestOpp',
            StageName = stageName,
            CloseDate = Date.today(),
            RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType where SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id
        );
        insert opp2;

        OpportunityLineItem lineItem2 = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = opp2.Id,
            UnitPrice = 10.00,
            Quantity = 3,
            PricebookEntryId = pbe1.Id      
        );


        insert new List<OpportunityLineItem> {lineItem1, lineItem2};


        OpportunityLineItem afterInsert = [SELECT Id, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :lineItem1.Id LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('UNIT PRICE = ' + afterInsert.UnitPrice);
        //System.assert(afterInsert.UnitPrice == 300.00);

        afterInsert = [SELECT Id, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :lineItem2.Id LIMIT 1];
        //System.assert(afterInsert.UnitPrice == 10.00);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, there's no point in using TRIM on fields loaded from the database, as they will never have leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: okay i will remove that

Answer (score 0):

This is answering the "how can I get the usertype of the user on before insert" part.

The `UserType` entry in this [User documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) includes this:

> The category of user license. Each UserType is associated with one or
>   more UserLicense records. Each UserLicense is associated with one or
>   more profiles.

I presume the field is populated as part of the User insert (or update) based on the Profile that is chosen.

So if you absolutely need to do something in `before insert`, you may be able to query the Profile and UserLicense objects to obtain the information. But the first thing I would try is to restructure the trigger to do the work in the after insert where the `User.UserType` could be queried to get its value.